# Calling a Kotlin function asynchronously from C++ with JNI

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm trying to call the function *initializationCallback* which is implemented in the Kotlin class *NativeConnector* from C++. I read that I first need to attach the current thread to the JVM, since the thread this code is executed from was not created by the JVM.

The attaching itself seems to be working/is not generating an error, but getting the method id fails with an error:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Running the code from a JVM created thread and without attaching it to the JVM again works perfectly fine, so it seems to me the problem is occurring during attachment.

```
JNIEnv *env;
int envStatus = javaVM->GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
if (envStatus == JNI_EDETACHED) {
    if (javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, nullptr) != 0) {
        Log::instance->logError(LOG_TAG, "AttachCurrentThread: failed.");
    }
}

auto clazz = env->FindClass("*/*/*/NativeConnector");
auto methodId = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "initializationCallback", "()V");
env->CallVoidMethod(m_connectorObject, methodId);

if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
}

javaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
```

Comment: Calling `FindClass` from a thread that you've attached yourself can be problematic. One solution to this is to resolve all necessary class references at startup (e.g. in `JNI_OnLoad`) and save them as global references for later use.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class for more info.

Comment: that solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in @Michael's comment.

Comment: @Botje comments are not answers, and a question being answered is not a reason for closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Michael in a comment:

Calling `FindClass` from a thread that you've attached yourself can be problematic. One solution to this is to resolve all necessary class references at startup (e.g. in `JNI_OnLoad`) and save them as global references for later use.

See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class for more info.